# Connecting more than 2 ethernets

Tags: networking, internet, connection, internet-connection, ethernet

I have a problem. I need to plug two RJ45 into 1 PC with 1  RJ45 plug so my question is. Is this possible to make form 2 cables one?

Comment: How many ports does your computer have? This question reads like an [XY problem.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: just one is working

Comment: And are you ok to explain why you want this? Some times it's easier to answer when we know the problem instead of working on a solution (hence my link to the XY problem (which is not meant to be read as rude :) )

Comment: Because I have in my house one unplugged Internet cable and i want to plug it in. And my ISP only grants access for specified MAC addresses. That's why I need to do this.

Comment: Bartosz, thank you for taking the to time to explain, but what do you hope to achieve from this?

Comment: I think that my Internet speed will rise or Internet traffic coming out  from my PC will be splitted on 2 cables

Comment: Remember, the speed is limited by the other side of the box, so if ISP provide 2mb and you get 2mb, then it won't get faster. If you're having a slow connection then that is a separate question (And the actual question)!

Comment: The simple solution would be to assign the mac address to a router.

Comment: I see, you want to combine both cables to surf faster. That's called link aggregation and can be done (see my answer below). But as Dave Rook has said I doubt you will get any noticeable speed increase. And you definitely need two Ethernet connectors.

Comment: Huh ok then. You are so helpful. I will probably go for hub.

Comment: I'm not sure a hub will work in your setup, your computer may have trouble accessing the Internet if the router announces its IP address over both interfaces via ARP. To be fair, link aggregation may not work either because those two cables are thought to be connected to two different computers, not to be combined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 cables wired together and plugged into the same jack would garble any message coming into the ethernet port, like 2 people talking to you, 1 in each ear.  A solution might be to buy an ethernet hub, connect the PC to it, and connect both cables into the hub.  Then, the hub could control the messages coming in from both cables. Hubs are inexpensive will serve the purpose you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "convert" or "merge" two Ethernet cables into one, but you can combine them using something called [link aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation):

> Link aggregation is a computer networking term to describe various
>   methods of combining (aggregating) multiple network connections in
>   parallel to increase throughput beyond what a single connection could
>   sustain

For **link aggregation to work you definitely need two Ethernet connectors**. Since you only have one you can use a ExpressCard/PCMCIA Ethernet adapter if your computer includes such an extension slot.

If you manage to get two Ethernet connectors working you can configure link aggregation like this:

- OS X: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH4156
- Windows Server: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/254101
- Windows: Windows does not offer this functionality in the core OS, you will need a driver that supports link aggregation (see [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-networking/does-windows-natively-support-link-aggregation/81e647f9-d89e-4028-8370-7e8bb0e3dc2f?msgId=6ca73c70-5ea7-4054-a75a-1be66d545b8a)).
- Linux: Linux includes a bonding driver. Configuration depends on distro.